# Как в Lua сформировать динамически название переменной?

Tags: lua

Есть два вопроса, которые не получается решить. Пожалуйста, помогите.

1. Как мне в функции добавить цифру из входного параметра функции "GetDescbyNum(abbr, **num**)"

   return (tbl[i]."desc"..tostring(num))

мне нужно, чтобы если num = 1, то

```
return (tbl[i].desc1)
```

если num = 2, то

```
return (tbl[i].desc2)
```

2. Как проверить существует ли эта динамически формируемая переменная в таблице,
   чтобы избежать ошибки?

MWE:

```
-- https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-lua-online/

tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ЯНАО", desc1="Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ", desc2="Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ОГКМ", desc1="Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="LED", desc1="Light emitting diode"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="FET", desc1="Field effect transistor"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ЛПР", desc1="Лицо, принимающее решения"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="БД", desc1="База данных"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="P2P", desc1="Peer-to-Peer"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="XML", desc1="extensible markup language"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="HTTP", desc1="Hypertext transfer protocol"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="SCADA", desc1="Supervisory control and data acquisition"})

print("-----------")

function ChangingLatinStr(s)
-- Проверяем первая буква латинская
-- если да, то добавляем ЯЯЯ
-- в остальных случаях возвращаем строку без изменений
if string.find(s:sub(1, 1), "%a") then
    return "ЯЯЯ" .. s
else
    return s
end
end

table.sort(tbl, function (a,b) return (ChangingLatinStr(a.abbr) < ChangingLatinStr(b.abbr)) end)

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(i, n.abbr, n.desc1)
end

print("-----------")

-- value = "SCADA"
value = "P2P"
for i = 1, #tbl do
    if tbl[i].abbr == value then
        print("--> " .. tbl[i].abbr, tbl[i].desc1)
--        break
    else
        print(i, tbl[i].abbr, tbl[i].desc1)
    end
end

print("-----------")

function GetDescbyNum(abbr, num)
    for i = 1, #tbl do
        if tbl[i].abbr == abbr then
--            return (tbl[i]."desc"..tostring(num))
            return (tbl[i].desc1)
--            break
        end
    end
end

print(GetDescbyNum("P2P", 1))
```

Comment: `print( tbl[i]["desc" .. tostring(num)] )`

Comment: а проверять наличие  `local tmp = "desc" .. tostring(num); if tbl[i][tmp] then return tbl[i][tmp]  else return "?"  end;`

Comment: Большое спасибо, @Mike V.